# Emacs OrgMode Global Cycling

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to get a custom type of *Global Cycling*.
When I use Shift+Tab I get

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt1tC.png)

I would like to know if is possible to have a level like

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOmww.png)

using the same command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(org-shifttab &optional ARG)
Just giving a numeric argument to shift-TAB according to the desired level.
EXAMPLE: C-2 Shift-TAB